# Eagle - Router does not understand wire jumpers?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I am using Eagle 7.2 - is there any setting which allows me to make Eagle understand wire jumpers? Neither the auto router nor the "show" button seems to be able to recognize that **2 wires connected by a wire-jumper have the same electrial potenial**. Maybe I am missing any setting?

Comment: Don't use the bloody autorouter! It's pure garbage (as with any other autorouter out there)! You'd have much better luck routing it yourself. It's not that difficult to do.

Comment: Hi derstrom8, thanks. Actually the autorouter in Version 7 is pretty good. This is the only thing I am missing. Btw. how do you route without the autorouter? You still use the ratsnest, right?

Comment: The autorouter in Version 7 is just as much of a piece of garbage as it was in Version 6. You use the routing tool to route manually. There are tons of tutorials out there. Yes, you would still use the ratsnest to fill polygons and show what connections still need to be made. You should ALWAYS learn to route manually before trying the autorouter. The autorouter will most likely ruin the layout and lead you astray. No machine can beat the intuition of a human being.

Comment: So my question was down-voted because I am asking about a feature someone doesn't prefer - haha.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. I expect it was downvoted because it shows an obvious lack of research, though.

Comment: @Der: The Eagle autorouter is a perfectly usable tool.  Like any tool, you have to learn to use it correctly, and there will always be things it can't do.  It is doing everyone else a disservice by disparaging the Eagle autorouter just because *you* haven't learned to use it properly.  The problem is with *you*, not with *it*.  I have used the autorouter to assist in routing quite a number of professional designs.  Then again, I've taken the time to learn to use it properly, and I don't expect it to solve all problems.  It can be very useful when used appropriately.

Comment: @Olin This member has admitted he doesn't even know how to route manually. Do you honestly think he's learned how to use the autorouter "properly"?

Comment: +1 because this is actually a good question.  There was talk of allowing pin definitions of a part so that the autorouter could know that particular pins were connected.  However, I don't remember hearing that this feature was ever implemented.

Comment: @Der: This isn't about this OP's abilities.  I am referring to your unqualified statements that the autorouter is "pure garbage".  You can make a mess with any tool, and you have to spend time to learn to use this one well, but that doesn't make the tool itself bad.

Comment: Fair enough Olin, but I still maintain that no machine can match the intuition of a real person.

Answer (score 8):

It wouldn't. You've told it that the net must be connected, but it has no way of knowing that your jumper wire is a connection. Anything in your schematic that you connect up must be connected with copper on the PCB.

For jumpers what I do is add an extra copper layer. If it's a one layer board, make eagle use two layers. Then connect the two sides of your jumper directly together on the new layer (do not place anything else on this layer).

For manufacturing, you simply don't generate Gerber data for the extra layer. So after manufacturing there will be no copper there and you can instead install your jumper.

Comment: +1.  This is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

add 2 times a 1 pin header, both pins connected to same signal.
That will work.

Comment: Thank you, sounds great - sorry for my bad knowledge, but how do I connect the pins to the same signal?

Comment: Not really - this appears to still leave the connection across the jumper component as an uncompleted airwire in the ratsnest, which is an annoyance to manual as well as automatic routing.

Answer (score 0):

As Cristian Mardones said, you can place 2x a 1 pin header, or create a component that simulates the same outcome. Still you should never be using a autorouter for a definite PCB. Use autoroute only to check for errors you may have made.